# Issues with Xamarin Forms 4 (pre 4) using CollectionView in UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm facing some tricky bugs while trying to use the new CollectionView
feature implemented in Xamarin Forms 4. On the `Android` project it works very
well after enabling experimental features in MainActivity.cs with:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new[] { "CollectionView_Experimental", "Shell_Experimental" });
```

But `xamarin` documentation doesn't provide any information about UWP project
so first when I tried to compile the UWP project, it throws me this exception
when it tries to render a page that uses CollectionView

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>
> 'The class, property, or method you are attempting to use ('VerifyCollectionViewFlagEnabled')
>   is part of CollectionView; to use it, you must opt-in by calling Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental")
>   before calling Forms.Init().'

So I tried to call the SetFlags in App.xaml.cs in UWP project before calling
InitializeComponent() method. So this time it throws me this exception when
it tries to load the page containing `CollectionView`:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

So like in this example:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageWithCollectionView());
```

The exception is thrown after successful execution of PageWithCollectionView constructor.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so adding the SetFlags in App.xaml.cs in UWP project works and
the CollectionView gets initialized correctly. But the NRE is still there
(on Android the CollectionView works without problems), while trying to get
rid of this problem I noticed that it's caused when I try to nest the XAML layout this way:

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Span="2"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

If I remove all the DataTemplate from CollectionView.ItemTemplate, just
leaving it blank like this:

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Span="2"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The page gets rendered a `CollectionView` shows ItemSource elements with messy
layout (without margin and padding, and calling `ToString()` method of element
to visualize it inside the cell).

**[UPDATE]**

After update to `Xamarin Forms` 4 pre 8, the exception is gone.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought `CollectionView` was not supported in UWP.

Comment: Since latest updates of XF, CollectionView is supported in UWP too

Answer (score 6):

I created  a code sample that contains [`CollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview). According to the document, we need call `SetFlag` before `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)` in the App.xaml.cs file like the following.

```
........

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

........
```

**Implement CollectionView**

```
<CollectionView>
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
</CollectionView>
```

And it works well, For `NullReferenceException` issue, you need check if there is null object in the code behind. Simple implementation of CollectionView does not cause such error.

**Update**

Please try to update **Xamarin Forms 4** to latest pre version.

Comment: Thank you, so SetFlags worked well but the NRE is still here. I updated the question providing more information about it

Comment: @BitZar, I used your ViewCell layout in my project and it works. I think the issue occurs in your  ItemsSource. Could your mind share a mini sample?

Comment: So I passed a lot of time searching to some kind of null value that may have been causing the exception but my model is ok, so I'll update my question with a sample of code

Comment: @BitZar, Could share a sample project for use that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: So after a long a debug searching for null references in my code I found nothing. But after update to Xamarin Forms 4 pre 8, the exception just vanished

Comment: @BitZar, Great, you could add this in the case update.

Answer (score 0):

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(“CollectionView_Experimental”);
```

use `MainActivity.cs` in Android